# Cannot get html() for parent span

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a simple thing maybe i am missing something:

```
var span = $(document.createElement("span")); // Create a span
var img = new Image(); // Create an image and set source
img.src = config.graph_url + member.facebook_id + "/picture?width=24&height=24";
span.append($(img)); // Add the image inside the span
```

How can i get the html `<span><img src="_SOURCE_"/></span>`? `span.html()` outputs `<img src="_SOURCE_"/>`.

Comment: Correct. That's how [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML)/[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html1) works.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2419877/174469 for the answer on how to get the outerhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine. The [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method sets or returns the content (innerHTML) of the selected elements

> In an HTML document, .html() can be used to get the contents of any element. If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the first match will have its HTML content returned.

So you can use [.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML) for this

```
$('span')[0].outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this  `<span><img src="_SOURCE_"/></span>`

Try something like this

```
$('span')[0].outerHTML;
```